# Right-click context menu appears slowly with two finger tap instead of two finger click

Tags: trackpad

In order to **right-click** or **secondary-click** I have elected to use a two-finger tap, like so:

[image]

The problem is that it always takes at least a second for the contextual menu to show up, sometimes slower. Is there a way to speed this up?

I have observed that if I perform a 2 finder click, the context menu appears fast against tapping with 2 fingers where it is slow to react.

Here are the specs on my machine:

[image]

Comment: NOTE: if I click with 2 fingers, it's fast. But if I tap with 2 fingers, it's slow to react.

Comment: Could you give us more informations, like the Model of the OSX Device?

Comment: we have accepted an answer to the OP, well done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A delayed reaction to a two-finger tap on a trackpad is caused by MacOS waiting to see if you are going to do a single two-finger tap or a double two-finger tap. Essentially, it thinks you might do another two-finger tap and it doesn't want to show the menu when you might be in the middle of a different gesture.

To speed it up, go to System Preferences > Trackpad > Scroll & Zoom and uncheck "Smart zoom." This will disable a feature that lets you zoom in on a specific thing (like a paragraph on a webpage) with a double two-finger tap.

Otherwise, if you want to keep Smart zoom enabled, you can wait the second for the context menu to appear with a two-finger tap, or you can do a two-finger click to make it faster.

As a side note, a similar thing happens on iOS devices. If you have an accessibility shortcut triggered by a triple-press of the home button, then double-pressing the home button is slower to bring up the app switcher. (This may be slightly different on the iPhone X which lacks a home button.)

Comment: nice that did the trick, bravo, makes sense

Comment: Does Apple know about this bug?

Comment: @You.Brighton I think it's meant to be this way intentionally to give you time to complete gestures with more taps.